# Assigning an enumerator and it's reverse to a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm stuck with this problem... I would like to enumerate in a regular for loop for one condition, and in reverse for another condition. Something like this:

```
var enumerator = 0..<length
if(stringPosition == .End) {
    enumerator = reverse(enumerator) //[C.Generator.Element] is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'
}
for index in enumerator {
    //do stuff
}
```

I'm getting a not convertible error there, and can't figure out how to proceed with that. I've tried different typecasting magic but that just doesn't work.

How should I sort out the conversion there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just casting to `Array` should work.

```
var enumerator = Array(0..<length) // <-- here
if(stringPosition == .End) {
    enumerator = reverse(enumerator)
    // then, enumerator.reverse() is better, I think
}
for index in enumerator {
    //do stuff
}
```

I think, more (memory) efficient way is like:

```
let range = lazy(0..<length)
let enumerator = stringPosition == .End ? SequenceOf(range.reverse()) : SequenceOf(range)
for index in enumerator {
    //do stuff
}
```

- `SequenceOf` is a wrapper of any `SequenceType`. You can use this to store different sequence type to one variable.
- for `lazy()`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24920812/3804019) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25227488/3804019).

Comment: I would give you 2 upvotes, but I can only give you 1 :) great answer, thanks!

Comment: Note that, the 2nd one is actually memory efficient, but much slower than 1st one.